# How can I generate an SVG version of an Android layout?

Tags: android, svg, programmatically-created

I want to generate the SVG image of Layout. Is there any way to generate it in android pragmatically? If yes then how?

Comment: "Is there any way to generate it in android pragmatically?" -- at best, only with difficulty, I would imagine.

Comment: Well, SVG is XML. You may try. Good luck!

Comment: @DerGolem currently i am generating bitmap of layout. But I want to generate SVG of layout programmatically. Dear please help me out.

Comment: Dear, this way a **too broad argument** (which is why I wished you `Good luck!`). The layout screenshot is a faster and surely working approach.